# Show array from apps script file in html file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an array of email drafts that I got in apps script. I want to show them in a html file in a select element, but it shows up blank when I run it. Code below

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("index");
}


function doSomething() {

  var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
  var drafty = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < drafts.length; i++){
    drafty.push(drafts[i].getMessage().getSubject());
  }
  Logger.log(drafty);
  return drafty;

  var select = document.getElementById("select"),
      arr = drafty;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
       var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
          txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);

        option.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
        option.appendChild(txt);
        document.getElementById("select").appendChild(option);
  }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="select" class="addon-select addon-form-input"></select>
  </body>
```

Comment: You might wish to change `onSelect` to `onChange`.

Comment: You currently have the JavaScript for setting up the select tag on the server.  It's not going to work there.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper - can you suggest how to change that?

Comment: Move it to the client.

Comment: @Cooper how does one do that? Do you mean add the gs to the html? If so, I tried that and when that's done, the GmailApp function doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:
gs:

```
function doSomething() {
  var drafts=GmailApp.getDrafts();
  var drafty=[];
  for(var i=0;i<drafts.length;i++){
    drafty.push(drafts[i].getMessage().getSubject());
  }
  Logger.log(drafty);
  return drafty;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(A){
        var id='select';
        var select = document.getElementById(id);
        select.options.length = 0; 
        for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(A[i],A[i]);
        }
      })
      .doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="select"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```